# remove lines containing strings from another file at specific index

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file called main_file with a variable number of columns. The first two columns of main_file are always with the same number of characters and the same field separator, and later there is various information. The information in the rest of the row can be anything, including the same as the first columns, so I cannot just grep the string. The lines are also not necessarily unique.

```
 aaaa  A --------- fdsfadf 
 aaaa  B --------- fasdfa
 bbbb  A --------- hgfhf
 bbbb  B --------- hftret jhtruyr
 1ulm  A --------- tret aaaa  A
 1ulm  X --------- fsdfs fdsfs
 1ulm  B --------- yttertre   ertre
 cccc  A --------- sdfsa      mjhhfdgdf
 cccc  B --------- werwfds     fsa wrew
 cccc  P --------- fsda   wrewr
 ghh1  A --------- rwerw     wrew
 ghh1  G --------- werwe    bbbb  B
 ghh2  A --------- Pewrew   trerew rwew
 ghh2  G --------- fdss         rewrw8
 ghh4  A --------- qweqe          321313
 ghh4  G --------- 3242   wrewrw
 aaaa  B --------- fasdfa erwrew
```

I have a file called code_list which contains all the entries that need to be removed from the file.

```
aaaa  A
aaaa  B
bbbb  A
bbbb  B
cccc  A
cccc  B
cccc  P
```

I would like to remove or comment out from main_file all the lines where there are entries from code_list

So I would like to get (in the same order):

```
* aaaa  A --------- fdsfadf 
* aaaa  B --------- fasdfa
* bbbb  A --------- hgfhf
* bbbb  B --------- hftret jhtruyr
 1ulm  A --------- tret aaaa  A
 1ulm  X --------- fsdfs fdsfs
 1ulm  B --------- yttertre   ertre
* cccc  A --------- sdfsa      mjhhfdgdf
* cccc  B --------- werwfds     fsa wrew
* cccc  P --------- fsda   wrewr
 ghh1  A --------- rwerw     wrew
 ghh1  G --------- werwe    bbbb  B
 ghh2  A --------- Pewrew   trerew rwew
 ghh2  G --------- fdss         rewrw8
 ghh4  A --------- qweqe          321313
 ghh4  G --------- 3242   wrewrw
* aaaa  B --------- fasdfa erwrew
```

or to get:

```
 1ulm  A --------- tret utrtry
 1ulm  X --------- fsdfs fdsfs
 1ulm  B --------- yttertre   ertre
 ghh1  A --------- rwerw     wrew
 ghh1  G --------- werwe    lkjl
 ghh2  A --------- Pewrew   trerew rwew
 ghh2  G --------- fdss         rewrw8
 ghh4  A --------- qweqe          321313
 ghh4  G --------- 3242   wrewrw
```

I tried running myscript.sh code_list

where myscript.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do


    awk '{if(substr($0,2,7) == "'$line'") {print "*"$0}else{print $0}}' main_file > out


done < "$1"
```

but I get an error "unterminated string"
When I tried

```
awk '{if(substr($0,2,7) == "aaaa  A") {print "*"$0}else{print $0}}' main_file > out
```

then it works. But the file code_list is way too long for me to write manually every name and I haven't been able to set it as a variable in any way.

What is the best way to remove or comment out these lines?

Comment: `awk '{if(substr($0,2,7) == "'$line'")` is inviting cryptic error messages like the one you got. Use `awk -v line="$line" '{if(substr($0,2,7) == line)` instead. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these my do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]++;next} {b=substr($0,2,7)} !(b in a)' filter data
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]++;next} !(($1"  "$2) in a)' filter data
 1ulm  A --------- tret aaaa  A
 1ulm  X --------- fsdfs fdsfs
 1ulm  B --------- yttertre   ertre
 ghh1  A --------- rwerw     wrew
 ghh1  G --------- werwe    bbbb  B
 ghh2  A --------- Pewrew   trerew rwew
 ghh2  G --------- fdss         rewrw8
 ghh4  A --------- qweqe          321313
 ghh4  G --------- 3242   wrewrw
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you can use the `NR == FNR` technique to have awk take care of processing both files. When `NR == FNR` it means that the record number being processed is the same as the record number within the current file, in other words, you are processing the first file in your argument list (`code_list` in this case).

The associated action for the first file is to build a lookup table for when we are processing the second file (`main_file`).

Because of the `next` statement in the first action, which tells awk to go immediately to the next record without doing any more actions, when we get to the second step we know we are processing the second file. The second step has only the condition that the first two fields not be in the lookup table. In that case it does the default action, which is to print the line.

```
 $ awk 'NR == FNR {a[$1 FS $2]; next} !(($1 FS $2) in a)' code_list main_file 
 1ulm  A --------- tret aaaa  A
 1ulm  X --------- fsdfs fdsfs
 1ulm  B --------- yttertre   ertre
 ghh1  A --------- rwerw     wrew
 ghh1  G --------- werwe    bbbb  B
 ghh2  A --------- Pewrew   trerew rwew
 ghh2  G --------- fdss         rewrw8
 ghh4  A --------- qweqe          321313
 ghh4  G --------- 3242   wrewrw
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{k=$1 FS $2} NR==FNR{a[k]; next} !(k in a)' code_list main_file
 1ulm  A --------- tret aaaa  A
 1ulm  X --------- fsdfs fdsfs
 1ulm  B --------- yttertre   ertre
 ghh1  A --------- rwerw     wrew
 ghh1  G --------- werwe    bbbb  B
 ghh2  A --------- Pewrew   trerew rwew
 ghh2  G --------- fdss         rewrw8
 ghh4  A --------- qweqe          321313
 ghh4  G --------- 3242   wrewrw

$ awk '{k=$1 FS $2} NR==FNR{a[k]; next} {print (k in a ? "*" : "") $0}' code_list main_file
* aaaa  A --------- fdsfadf
* aaaa  B --------- fasdfa
* bbbb  A --------- hgfhf
* bbbb  B --------- hftret jhtruyr
 1ulm  A --------- tret aaaa  A
 1ulm  X --------- fsdfs fdsfs
 1ulm  B --------- yttertre   ertre
* cccc  A --------- sdfsa      mjhhfdgdf
* cccc  B --------- werwfds     fsa wrew
* cccc  P --------- fsda   wrewr
 ghh1  A --------- rwerw     wrew
 ghh1  G --------- werwe    bbbb  B
 ghh2  A --------- Pewrew   trerew rwew
 ghh2  G --------- fdss         rewrw8
 ghh4  A --------- qweqe          321313
 ghh4  G --------- 3242   wrewrw
* aaaa  B --------- fasdfa erwrew
```

Comment: Do you need the next?.  `awk '{k=$1 FS $2} NR==FNR{a[k]} !(k in a)'` gives same result

Comment: technically, no you don't in that case since we have the `!` operator but you would if you were testing for `in` rather than `!in` ad you do in the second case. I'd prefer to always have it just to be clear we're only doing the `in` processing for the 2nd file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to convert the data in file `code_list` to patterns for `grep`, anchored to the beginning of the line

```
sed 's/^/^/' code_list > code_list2
```

Edit: This will work if both `code_list` and `main_file` contain the same leading spaces.

Assuming the file `code_list` contains exactly one leading space, the resulting file `code_list2` will contain

```
^ aaaa  A
^ aaaa  B
^ bbbb  A
^ bbbb  B
^ cccc  A
^ cccc  B
^ cccc  P
```

If the leading spaces might be different (or not present), the substitution can be extended:

```
sed 's/^ */^ */' code_list > code_list2
```

This removes any number of leading spaces and adds a pattern for any number of leading spaces. Handling tabs as well would require additional changes.

The resulting file `code_list2` will contain

```
^ *aaaa  A
^ *aaaa  B
^ *bbbb  A
^ *bbbb  B
^ *cccc  A
^ *cccc  B
^ *cccc  P
```

(end of edit)

Then use this to extract the lines that don't match

```
grep -v -f code_list2 main_file
```

With this I get

```
 1ulm  A --------- tret aaaa  A
 1ulm  X --------- fsdfs fdsfs
 1ulm  B --------- yttertre   ertre
 ghh1  A --------- rwerw     wrew
 ghh1  G --------- werwe    bbbb  B
 ghh2  A --------- Pewrew   trerew rwew
 ghh2  G --------- fdss         rewrw8
 ghh4  A --------- qweqe          321313
 ghh4  G --------- 3242   wrewrw
```

If you use a shell that supports `<( command )`, e.g. `bash`, you can combine the two commands as

```
grep -v -f <(sed 's/^/^/' code_list) main_file
```

Edit: or to handle different leading spaces

```
grep -v -f <(sed 's/^ */^ */' code_list) main_file
```

Comment: thanks it works but I'd like to know how does sed "know" that we are only looking for this pattern in the substring of 2nd to 7th index (the first fields),and not later in the line, which would choose also the line e.g. 1ulm  A --------- tret aaaa  A?

Comment: @Layla_K - the key is the phrase _"anchored to the beginning of the line"_. sed isn't looking at 2nd to 7th, it is trying to match the pattern at the start of the line. and why **2nd** to 7th, does your input contain a leading space? That is, is it `.aaaa  A` or is it `aaaa  A`? (where the dot here represents a space)

Comment: @Stephen yes, the input contains a leading single space ( [.aaaa..A] so leading single space and then double space between aaaa and A). So although it is "anchored to the beginning of the line", it skips the leading space?

Comment: @Layla_K It was not clear that the leading space was intentional. You should add this information to the question. I will modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Layla_K - I think Bodo's answer was assuming no space at the start. S/he is transforming the code_list file into patterns and anchoring it to the start of the line using `^` but probably just missed the leading space. You can keep your code_list file simple, without the leading space, and add the space when transforming the file. `sed 's/^/^/' code_list > code_list2` would become `sed 's/^/^ /' code_list > code_list2` (note the added space between the 2nd `^` and the final `/`) The first pattern in Bodo's "The resulting file" would then be `^ aaaa  A`—a space before `a` and 2 before the `A`